# Почему не подставляется значение в value?

Tags: php, javascript, html5-canvas, fingerprint

В общем этот код работает лишь в Firefox 54, во всех остальных браузер не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
function fingerprint() {
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var txt = "browser";
ctx.textBaseline = "top";
ctx.font = "14px 'Arial'";
ctx.textBaseline = "alphabetic";
ctx.fillStyle = "#f60";
ctx.fillRect(125,1,62,20);
ctx.fillStyle = "#069";
ctx.fillText(txt, 2, 15);
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(102, 204, 0, 0.7)";
ctx.fillText(txt, 4, 17);
var strng=canvas.toDataURL();

document.body.appendChild(canvas);    

var hash=0;
if (strng.length==0) return 'nothing!';
for (i = 0; i < strng.length; i++) {
char = strng.charCodeAt(i);
hash = ((hash«5)-hash)+char;
hash = hash & hash;
  }
  return hash;
}


var search = fingerprint();
$("input[type=text]").val(search);

$(function(){
    $(document).on('submit', '[data-action="adds"]', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize()
      }).done(function (data) {

      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
<form name="form" id="form" action="view_text.php" method="POST" data-action="adds">
<input type="text" name="search" value="">
<input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
document.forms["form"].submit();
}
</script>
```

В файле `view_txt.php` прсотенький код занесений строки в файл, заносится пустое значение.

Но, если без автоматической отправки формы, тогда всё работает нормально во всех браузерах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо

```
window.onload = function() {
document.forms["form"].submit();
}
```

написать

```
$(function(){
   $('#form').submit();
});
```

Может быть так, что страница уже загрузилась, а вот jquery еще не запустился.

Comment: спасибо большое, а я правильно всё сделал по получению фингерпринта? его просто не изменить как юзер-агента или IP?